# Segmented Paging mechanism virtual and physical pages

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems

I have a system which uses segmented paging. Every address is divided as follows: 
(s,p,d) = 2,2,11. Main memory has a capacity of 32KB. There are 4 segments which have 4 virtual pages each. I have to find the number of physical and virtual pages. For the virtual pages i suppose that the answer is 16 because every segment has 4 virtual pages. To calculate the number of physical pages i converted the 32KB of memory to bits and divide the number by 2^11 so the answer is 125. Is that correct?

Comment: I agree about the 16 virtual pages : 32KB of virtual memory divided into 16 2KB pages. For physical, it could have any size, it could be 32KB of physical memory, it could be more.

Comment: Yes but how many physical pages fit in the memory? How do i calculate it?